# How to Fix "has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable' "

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm performing create and read operation and for that, I used FirebaseListObservable in my application. What should I import and where should I mention.

I tried updating the dependencies but still, I am getting the same error

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable < any[] > ;
  msg: string = '';

  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = af.list('/messages');
  }

  send(chatMsg: string) {
    this.items.push({
      message: chatMsg
    });
    this.msg = '';
  }
}
```

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,31): error TS2305: Module '"/home/manoj/Desktop/R&D/chatapp/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.

Comment: Which version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: I am using "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",

Comment: did you import the angularfire2 module in to your `AppModule`?

Comment: This is how i have imported: import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the types?[firebase types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/firebase)

Comment: Is it required to install this one as i checked it is deprecated ?

Comment: Maybe you are right, do you have firebase installed? i have 5.7.0